# Logic behind ArgoCD sync of Application

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, gitops

I wanted to force a sync of an Application in ArgoCD (v2.7.8) to re-create all resources, even if not all of them were updated in a Git repository. I didn't find any documentation specific for this case, but somehow I've managed to make it using the following arguments (body) for a `/api/v1/applications/{name}/sync` operation:

```json
{
    "prune": true,
    "strategy": {
        "hook": {
            "force": true
        }
    },
    "syncOptions": {
        "items": ["Replace=true"]
    }
}
```

But this set of parameters makes me confused, because every options shall not destroy and re-create a resource, if it was not modified in the repository.

1. The 'prune' option shall remove a resource if it is not defined in Git, but no resources are deleted from the repository in my case. (https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/auto_sync/#automatic-pruning, https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-kubectl/#prune).
2. The 'force' option shall add '--force' to 'kubectl' command, but that shall not influence whether the resource shall be updated or replaced (https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#replace-resource-instead-of-applying-changes).
3. The 'Replace=true' option shall use 'kubectl replace' instead of 'apply', but it shall  not influence whether the resource shall be updated or replaced (https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#replace-resource-instead-of-applying-changes).

How and why does it work in my case?

Comment: Are you sure about the strategy.hook.force ? When I look at my swagger documentation (argocd version 2.9.2) It should rather be startegy.hook.syncStrategyApply.force